# How to reduce load on JBoss Fuse Karaf running Camel routes with ActiveMQ?

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf, fuse

I have a broken system running JBoss Fuse 7.5 and 6.3 with Karaf, Camel routes, and ActiveMQ. The main purpose of the system is to move data from A to B using various protocols.

The system was designed over 10 years ago where it worked fine handling a few dozen routes. However the demand has grown from a few dozen to a thousand or more. The load is too much. Routes are breaking and we are losing data, running out of memory, exhausting resources, etc.

I need to keep the system running without error until the replacement system comes online which will be a while. We are required to use the hardware we have. We cannot increase processing power by adding a VM.

Some ideas I have.  I am not sure if these can be done.

1. Restrict number of concurrent processes.
2. Configure camel routes to run only during certain times of the day.  Or have a method to spread the load out over time.

Any suggestions on what can be done?

Comment: A representative camel route would be helpful.  Have you either disabled, or severely restricted, the message prefetch?  The default value is 1000.  In Camel (or more specifically, Spring JMS), I find that disabling the prefetch completely is best.  If you are running out of file handles, then you will need to use the pooling connection factory so that the JMS connection/session can be reused.

Comment: Thanks for your input Justin. All camel routes are using ActiveMQConnectionFactory.  I think the problem is that there are too many concurrent connections.  Is there a way to restrict the number of concurrent connections? Is there a process timeout that can be adjusted when a route must wait for a connection?

Comment: There are many ways to tune Red Hat Fuse. I suggest to get in touch with the vendor they can better offer advice